# How to make multilanguage realurl in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, multilingual, realurl

I have one problem with multilingual realurl. I want the key of the URL parameter to be multi language.

For example: I have below URL for the default (English) language.

```
http://www.example.com/xyz-page/company-detail/company-name.html
```

here "company-detail" is the key parameter of the URL parameter "&tx_company[company]=1" where tx_company[company] is converted to "company-detail" through postVarSets.

Now in German I want the above URL like below

```
http://www.example.com/xyz-page/firma-detail/company-name.html
```

And in French I want the above URL like below

```
http://www.example.com/xyz-page/entreprises-detail/company-name.html
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: any answer? I welcome help too!

Comment: Is a solution still needed?